# ! File ended while scanning use of \IMOpaper

Tags: errors

I've been trying to preview my paper but I keep getting the error:

Runaway argument?
{ \par \title {An End-Height Criterion for NASA's All-Sky Fireball Ne\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \IMOpaper.
 
                \par 
<*> Fireball_End_Height.tex

I sifted through the whole document to make sure I didn't have any stray or missing } but nothing. Does anyone know of another reason why it's doing this? Here's the beginning and end of the input.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,dvips]{article}
%% Needed for wgn2.sty
\usepackage{vmargin, fancyhdr, amsmath, setspace, dcolumn, ifthen}
\usepackage{wgn2}
% Althea added this to deal with all the overfull hboxes -- remove for     %submission
\usepackage{setspace}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\SetPaperBodyFont


\begin{IMOpaper}{twocol}{

\title{An End-Height Criterion for NASA's All-Sky Fireball Network}
\author{Jessica L. Page,\thanks{NASA Meteoroid Environment Office, 
Marshall Space Flight Center, Huntsville, Alabama 35812}}
```

...

```
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\bibliography{PE}


\end{IMOpaper}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hard to tell with just fragments. But you seem to have an extra opening curly bracket at the end of the `\begin{IMOpaper}...` line. I'm guessing that is never closed. Do you need it at all? Does the environment require a second argument?

Comment: There is a closing `}` missing. It is the one for `\begin{IMOpaper}{twocol}{`

Comment: Yes, I tried both suggestions and adding a `}` at the end produces an error underfull hboxes. When I remove the brackets all together I get other errors. It must be another issue that I need to work out. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: `underfull hbox` is a warning not an error. Make a complete example which shows the error.

Comment: This is the message I get after adding the `}` at the end

Comment: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 331--331

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ace *{-2.32\baselineskip } \balance 
                                                  \par \thispagestyle {empty...
l.331 }
       
?

Comment: When I remove the brackets completely, I get Overfull \hbox (250.01381pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 33--34
[] 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 33--34

! Undefined control sequence.
l.39 \balance and lines 33-34 are the first couple of lines of my abstract.

Comment: The error seems caused by the blank line after the opening brace. Remove it. Since the `wgn2.sty` package is not on CTAN, can you point to a source for it?

Comment: I obtained it from a share, I couldn't find it online either. Do you think the style file might have something to do with it? Perhaps I'm not compiling it correctly. I've looked into something called latexmk for things like this. Would this be a better option? @egreg

Comment: How can we know what the `IMOpaper` environment is doing without seeing the package defining it? Did you try removing the blank line before `\title` as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, same error. I didn't think we could upload files to this site, but I'll look into the actual environment itself and see what could be wrong. I'll also try to find a source for the wgn2.sty and I'll tag you. Thank you! @egreg